# vue-router 4 dynamic path with parameter not found

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I'm using dynamic URLs in my Vue 3 app

```
const routes = [...
  {
    path: "/vehicles/:id",
    name: "VehicleVehiclePage",
    component: import(
      /* webpackChunkName: "vehicles" */ "../components/management/Vehicles/VehiclePage.vue"
    ),
    props: true
  },
...]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
})
```

Everything works as expected locally, but in production I get 404, so for some reason the router is not working as locally. I also tried

```
GET http://mywebsite.com/vehicles/659d0ee27e31f1b0dc2cedd1 404 (The requested content does not exist.)
```

hosted client side, in Azure Storage 
vue version - 3.2.47 
vue-router version - 4.2.5

PS: I also tested `createWebHashHistory`; I don't get the error anymore, but the page is blank, not loaded. I can't see any logs from `created()`, `mounted()` or other places.

Comment: are you using nginx to serve this? if so, you'll need to route 404 paths to the index.html file

Comment: did you take same error for all routes ?

Comment: the error is just for the dynamic routes. not using nginx, it's a client side hosted app in an Azure Storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it working. It seems if I don't use lazy loading it works...weird.

```
    {
        path: "/vehicles/:id",
        name: "VehiclePage",
        component: VehiclePage,
        props: true
      }
```